# How to ZIP folder with files and subfolders in TOS - which component should I use?

Tags: etl, talend

I'm trying to understand how to ZIP folder with files and subfolders in TOS.

which component should I use ?

Please help me I'm a newbie.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

using tFileArchive

In fact , this component will archive your files using a specific directory .

Please check this officiel documentation ,

[https://help.talend.com/r/FPXyrzjjrbRPT_aQ4GP99g/og4_P6hnwisyF~hJLTMtQw](https://help.talend.com/r/FPXyrzjjrbRPT_aQ4GP99g/og4_P6hnwisyF%7EhJLTMtQw)

[image: tFileArchive componenet]